# ora-1653 unable to extend table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to import an Oracle Schema to a new BBDD:

```
impdp ******/****** schemas=SCHEMA dumpfile=SCHEMA_2016-09-16_%u.dpdmp
```

But I get this error:

```
ORA-39171: Job is experiencing a resumable wait.
ORA-01653: unable to extend table SCHEMA.ELEMENTS by 8192 in tablespace SCHEMA_DAT1
```

My TABLESPACE and DATAFILES are in "AUTOEXTEND ON" mode:

```
create tablespace SCHEMA_DAT1 datafile '/ora01/app/oracle/oradata/fgh/DATAFILES/SCHEMA_DAT1.dbf' SIZE 4096M AUTOEXTEND ON;
alter database datafile '/ora01/app/oracle/oradata/fgh/DATAFILES/SCHEMA_DAT1.dbf' autoextend on maxsize unlimited;
```

The error is very strange and i can't find a solution.

Comment: Datafiles do not extend forever. They do have a limit, which is about 4M blocks. For 8K blocks is a little below 32GB. Check tablespaces current size (as you didn't specify a maxsize). If needed, add datafiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need a lot more DataFiles because the limit is `32GB` per file. Thanks.